# JavaScript dynamic variable name according to another variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
onClick={ this.props.remove(this.props. + this.props.title) }
```

How can I accomplish to have `this.props.custom_variable_name` which is coming from the variable `this.props.title`
This example doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
onClick={() => this.props.remove(this.props[this.props.title])}
```

Comment: That's nice and solves the OP's problem when you're dealing with named *properties* of objects, not actual *variables*. Let me add, that in case of *variables*, your solution is `eval`. Like in `this.props.remove(eval(title));`. It would work with properties too, but not only is it vastly slower, it's actually pretty risky (enabling code injection attacks if not safeguarded enough.)

Comment: return <Item remove={this.remove} title={item.title} key={idx} item={item} sortData={idx} {item.title}={idx} isDraggable={true} />;
            }.bind(this));

Ok, i have this line in React which is iterating with several Items , and I am trying to make this Item unique by passing **{item.title}** as parameter name, but it is giving me syntax error. How can I make this parameter work so every Item has custom parameter?

Comment: There's a point where a one-liner should stop being a one-liner and become a helper function...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
onClick={ () => this.props.remove(this.props[this.props.title]) }
```

Comment: @Vikast could you post your code where do you use  `this.props.remove`? As I understood you have loop, could you post it?

Comment: @Vikast could you give feedback?